# OpenGL shader builder errors on compiling

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm using OpenGL shader builder v2.2.2 and took sample code from book.
For vertex shader

```
#version 140
uniform float CoolestTemp;
uniform float TempRange;
uniform mat4  MVPMatrix;
in  vec4  mcVertex;
in  float VertexTemp;

out float Temperature;
void main() {

    Temperature = (VertexTemp - CoolestTemp) /  TempRange;
    gl_Position = MVPMatrix * mcVertex;
}
```

And for fragment shader

```
#version 140

uniform vec3 CoolestColor;
uniform vec3 HottestColor;

in float Temperature;
out vec4 FragmentColor;

void main() 
{    
    vec3 color = mix(CoolestColor, HottestColor, Temperature);
    FragmentColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

My problem is to execute this code because version 140 and 320 is not supported. Then I tryed to remove versions, compiler said "Invalid qualifiers 'in' in global variable context" and same for 'out', then tried to replace in/out to 'varying' but in fragment shader "Left-hand-side of assignment must not be read-only" error appears. For vertex shader have warning about varying fields will not read in next stages. 
How can I figure out it to adapt an old-styled code to new?
So I'm absolutely new to GLSL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's much more common to go from the old naming to new. But if you need the other way, the conversion for the vertex shader is:

```
in --> attribute
out --> varying
```

For fragment shader:

```
in --> varying
out --> (delete)
```

For the `out` of the fragment shader, you can delete the declaration of the variable. Instead, use the built-in `gl_FragColor` variable.

For your example, the vertex shader will look like this:

```
uniform float CoolestTemp;
uniform float TempRange;
uniform mat4  MVPMatrix;
attribute vec4  mcVertex;
attribute float VertexTemp;
varying float Temperature;

void main() {
    Temperature = (VertexTemp - CoolestTemp) /  TempRange;
    gl_Position = MVPMatrix * mcVertex;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
uniform vec3 CoolestColor;
uniform vec3 HottestColor;
varying float Temperature;

void main() {
    vec3 color = mix(CoolestColor, HottestColor, Temperature);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: finally some clear information, thank you very much!